# Click on image in React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, native

I am working on an app that uses images and when the image is clicked, a new random image from a folder is to display. This is in React Native. I have no clue how to do it or where to go to get more information. Here is the code.

```
      <Image
        style={{ 
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
        source={
          require('./cards/card.png')
        }
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

Pressable is another option. 
You can check React documentation here.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction}>
      <Image
        style={{ 
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
        source={
          require('./cards/card.png')
        }
      />
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `<Image />` component with `TouchableOpacity` other `Touchable` component. And make the image source dynamic using props or state.

For instance :

Your state

```
const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState('')

const handlePress = () => {
   // some logic random the image
}
```

Your component

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
    <Image source={{
          uri: imageUri
        }}/>
<TouchableOpacity>
```

Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity